How to Ensure that the --make-iptables-util-chains argument is set to true in Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) Standard
I have a task to harden GKE based on the CIS Benchmark. One of the tasks assigned is to ensure the --make-iptables-util-chains argument is set to true. How do I do this?
I have already checked the kubelet-config.yaml file, but I didn't find that configuration there.
